# How to block addresses that don't have a domain name (IP only) using Unbound?

Tags: dns, unbound

With Unbound I've been able to block proxy websites with domain names.
IE: croxy.org

But many proxy website mirrors don't use domain names.
IE: https://67.207.72.190

I was curious, is there a way **with Unbound** to block all addresses (like 67.207.72.190) that do not have a domain name?

I tried consulting the unbound.conf man page but most examples regarding IP addresses seemed to relate to local IPs.

I'm not even sure if Unbound is being used when you visit an IP directly in the browser that doesn't return a domain name.

Answer (score 1):

### The answer is no

Unbound is a DNS server/resolver. IP addresses are not subject to domain name resolution and therefore cannot be filtered by Unbound.

If you control the network/devices in question, you can use a firewall to filter outbound traffic by destination IP, among other things.